# Creating a user who can only access a single page

Tags: confluence

I am currently writing a script which has to curl a certain confluence page and parse it. Now I want to place the credentials directly into the script.

Therefore I need to create a Confluence user which is only allowed to read that single page. Is that possible (without having to manually restrict all other pages)?

Alternatively (2nd best): Is it possible to make one single page readable without login?

Answer (score 0):

The best I found until now is a user which is only allowed to read one space.

1. create a new account e.g. foo https://yourdomain/admin/users/createuser.action
2. remove default membership of that account to any groups https://yourdomain/admin/users/editusergroups-start.action?username=foo
3. allow user to use confluence  https://yourdomain/admin/permissions/editglobalpermissions.action
4. allow user to read the space the page is in https://yourdomain/spaces/spacepermissions.action?key=yourspace